# Windows 10 pro event log file is corrupted

Tags: windows-event-log, logparser

I'm trying to read event log with LogParser on windows 10 pro, and the query `select * from security` executed well.

But I'm getting a message saying that the file is corrupted After executing the query `select count(*) from security`. Does anybody like me?

And `System event` also shows the same result. But `Application event` executed well all query. For reference, all events read well in Event Viewer.

Comment: After clearing the log, the logparser reads it well.

Comment: If you have solved this, consider adding an answer and accepting it. It is not appropriate here to add the word "solved" to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After clearing the log, the logparser reads it well.